# NPM package issues when running meteor app

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, meteorite

Right now, I'm trying to get [Telescope](http://telesc.pe) to run locally on my Mac. I go through all the steps, but once I type in

```
meteor
```

in terminal, this is what I get:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
fast-render: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Justin/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Justin/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/Justin/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'readable-stream' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "/Users/Justin/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/node" "/Users/Justin/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/npm" "install" "connect@2.13.0"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Justin/.meteorite/packages/fast-render/arunoda/meteor-fast-render/149984b1aff3a5642a270aff9bd9006872c8302e/.npm/package-new-26ztfl
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /Users/Justin/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Justin/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Justin/.meteorite/packages/fast-render/arunoda/meteor-fast-render/149984b1aff3a5642a270aff9bd9006872c8302e/.npm/package-new-26ztfl/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building package `fast-render`:
error: couldn't install npm package

While building package `telescope-tags`:
error: no such package: 'iron-router'

While building package `telescope-search`:
error: no such package: 'iron-router'
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: the error message says you don't have permissions to access `~/.npm/`

Comment: As the other person said, you don't have permissions, try `sudo meteor`

Comment: DON'T do `sudo ...`, try to change ownership first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290986/how-to-fix-eacces-issues-with-npm-install/29787931#29787931

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/893

From the post:

"Looking in my .meteor/local directory, I saw that .meteor/local/build was owned by root instead of my normal user. Running a `sudo rm -r build` from within .meteor/local fixed the problem."